# Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake, bundler

This is an odd one. I'm getting this error when I run rake to do tests but not when I migrate. I'm running RVM, the shell dump below should give any information you need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've seen a few other people with this issue, but no solutions that worked for me yet (or them).

Thanks.

```
$ rake
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
Errors running test:units, test:functionals, test:integration!



$ ruby -v
    ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0]
    $ rails -v
    Rails 3.1.6

$ more .rvmrc 
rvm ruby-1.9.3-p194@...
$ rake db:rollback
==  AddAllLocationsToAlert: reverting =========================================
-- remove_column(...
   -> 0.0320s
==  AddAllLocationsToAlert: reverted (0.0321s) ================================
```

------- EDIT::::

I have since upgraded to the latest Rails - 3.2.6. The error still occurs, even if I use 'bundle exec'. (This is not new to 3.2.6 - I was still getting the issue under 3.1) The undefined method is new though.

```
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
$ bundle exec rake
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
Errors running test:units! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
Errors running test:functionals! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (7): [/Users/ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin...]>
Errors running test:integration! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (7): [/Users/ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin...]>
```

My Gemfile, as requested:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.6'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.2.5"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.2.1"
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.6'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'rake'
gem "mysql2"

gem "squeel"
gem 'tinymce-rails'
gem 'dynamic_form'

gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'devise'
gem 'whitelist'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'json'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'acts_as_list', :git => 'https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list'
gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'formtastic'
# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

Comment: 'gem install rake' doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe on of the gems in `test` group of your Gemfile depends on different version of `rake` than the one installed in your system.

Comment: Bender: Nope. :(

Michal: Now that hints at an idea of what may be going on. I don't have a test group in the Gemfile - this is based on an old project. It's been pulled up from rails 1 through 3.0, 3.1 and now 3.2, so I'm not using the full feature set. However, there are some old gems hanging around in there. One could be causing some Rake issues perhaps.

Odd that it's only testing I'm getting it on so far. Why does a migrate work?

Comment: Nope, same error when I temporarily remove all gems but the default rails ones. Thanks though.

Comment: For anyone that cares, I found that I was getting the error deploying a Rails 3.2 site to a server expecting Rails 3.0. It was running Passenger and the error caused the site to fail. Turned out that Passenger needs to run the same version of Ruby that the site is running. It was compiled for an older Ruby version. After a hellish time compiling a new Passenger, I found that the recompile worked. I could be referencing an old Gem compiled under an old Ruby version...

Answer (score 3):

gem 'rake', ">=0.9.2" # in your Gemfile

then

$ bundle install

then

$ bundle exec rake

if above not worked :

$ rvm all do gem install rake -v 0.9.2.2#install rake to all ruby versions

then run rake again

Comment: That's a helpful little rmv command, @Ahmed.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bundler (and with rails, you probably do), always run rake like this:

`bundle exec rake`

This will pick up gems specified in your Gemfile.

Comment: That was one of the potential solutions offered in the other similar threads. Unfortunately... No. L:(

Comment: Updated initial post to reflect that this suggestion fails. (So no sarky comments, readers)

Comment: By the way, I've always been confused by this feature. It's really irritating!

In the past I got round it by uninstalling the gem versions I didn't want, but at the moment I only have one version - the one it's asking for!

I can only assume that somewhere in the code a dependency isn't met and the error message is confusedly returning the current gem version rather than the one required... But I have no idea how to dig deeper here.

Comment: Please post also your Gemfile - how exactly do you require `rake` in it.

Comment: This is just a guess, but try to change `gem 'rake'` into `gem 'rake', '~> 0.9.2'` or `gem 'rake', '~> 0.9.2.2'` and try again: `bundle install`, `bundle exec rake`

Comment: I wish it were that simple. No change I'm afraid.